# Unity3d trigger event action to change a text in a canvas after another object passes through a trigger

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble with a script in unity

tried something like this but it didn't work

```
public Collider a;
public Text text;

void update(){

 if(a.collision.tag == "object")

   text.text = "Trigger works";

}
```

then attached the game elements to those public variables in the editor.

Answer (score 3):

First `update` is not MonoBehaviour function. It is `Update` .

Secondly you should watch [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders).

You need add `Collider` to your `GameObject` then set the colliders `Is Trigger` field true.

After that you need to add [OnTriggerEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) and/or [OnTriggerExit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html) and/or [OnTriggerStay](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html) to your script.

for example:

```
//public Collider a;   
public Text text;

void Update(){
   //dont need to use Update.
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "object"){
        //set text whatever you want.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

triggers only get triggered from the `OnTriggerEnter`, `OnTriggerStay`, `OnTriggerExit` methods

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){

 if(col.tag == "object")

   text.text = "Trigger works";

}
```